# Closed set and limit points

Tags: general-topology

I was asked to prove that a set $X$ is closed if and only if it contains all its limit points. I proceeded like so:

Let $X^\dagger=\partial X \cap X´$ and $X^\ast=\partial X \backslash X´$ with $X´$ being the derived set of $X$. If $X$ is closed then:
$$X=int(X) \,\cup \,\partial X =int(X) \, \cup \,(X^\dagger \,\cup\,X^\ast)= $$
$$=(int(X)\,\cup\, X^\dagger)\, \cup \, X^\ast= $$
$$=X´ \, \cup \, X^\ast$$
Therefore if $X$ is closed then it contains all its limit points. I.e, $X$ is closed if and only if $X´\subseteq X$.

Is this correct, and if so, what are some better ways to prove this?

Comment: You might want to explain what you are trying to do. What is a derived set?

Comment: @copper.hat The derived set of a set S is the set of all the limit points of S. In other words, a point c belongs to the derived set of S if there is a sequence of points of S whose limit is c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to drag the boundary and derived sets into the proof.

Suppose $X$ is closed and $p$ is a limit point of $X$. Suppose $p \notin X$. Since $X^c$ is open and $p \in X^c$, we must have $X^c \cap X$ is non empty which is impossible, hence $p \in X$.

Now suppose $X$ contains all its limit points. Suppose $p \notin X$. Then there must be some neighbourhood $U$ containing $p$ that does not intersect $X$ (otherwise $p$ would be a limit point). Hence $X^c$ is open and so $X$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $a_n \in X$, and $a_n \to a$, if $a \notin X$, $a\in X'$, then $\exists \epsilon, B(a,\epsilon)\in X'$. So $\exists N$, when $n>N$, $a_n \in X'$. Conflict.

If it contains all its limit points. Consider $\forall a \in X'$, if $\forall \epsilon$, $B(a,\epsilon) \notin X'$, assume $a_n \in B(a,\epsilon_n)\cap X$, we have $a_n\to a, a\notin X$. Conflict. Therefore, $\exists \epsilon, B(a,\epsilon) \in X'$.

Comment: Note that in general (topological spaces), sequences are not sufficient to describe the closure.